# zftp connection refused, sftp works

Tags: zsh, sftp, ftp

When I try to sftp into a virtual machine's IP address it works well (I am able to do all the sftp provided operations). But when I try to use zsh's zftp for the same IP address, the connection is refused. I tried different flavors of the command, but none work. Here's a sample:

```bsh
❯ autoload -U zfinit ; zfinit
❯ zftp open 10.211.55.8
zftp open: connect failed: connection refused
```

Other command flavors I tried: `❯ zftp open '10.211.55.8'`, and `zftp open '[10.211.55.8]'`

Note: zsh 5.8 is installed on both machines. zftp does not work from either machine, sftp works from either machine trying to connect to the other.

System information: Virtual machine I am trying to connect to is Arch Linux (it has zsh installed and running as my default shell). The machine I am trying to connect to is macOS 11.6, which too has zsh as its default shell.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader No clue how to do that. When I search "zserv" in zsh pdf manual, it returns no hits.

Comment: perhaps you are trying to connect to the standard ftp port 21 ? `ZFTP_PORT
Readonly. The number of the remote TCP port to which the connection is open (even if the port was originally specified as a named service). Usually this is the standard FTP port, 21.`

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Perhaps, I don't know. Am new to this, in past I have used sftp and it just works with simple syntax like ``sftp 10.211.55.8``, am looking forward to do some setup that can enable the same for zftp. Its a bit late here, there will be delay in reply... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`zsh/zftp` is an [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) client. `sftp` is an [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) client. FTP and SFTP are completely different protocols. SFTP is a file transfer protocol over SSH, but it isn't FTP over SSH.

`zftp open 10.211.55.8` would only work if there was an FTP server on 10.211.55.8, whereas `sftp 10.211.55.8` works on most non-embedded systems that have an SSH server (it's a feature of OpenSSH and it's usually enabled by default). FTP, like rsh, has largely been displaced by SSH<sup>1,2</sup>.

`zftp` was developped largely due to the relative complexity of FTP. There wouldn't be much point in doing something similar for SFTP. Usually, if you have SFTP access, you also have SSH shell access and SCP access, and you can use `scp` to copy files (zsh will provide completion, so you don't need `ls` much).

To make SFTP more seamless, you can use [SSHFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSHFS) to mount the remote server's directory tree locally. It requires SFTP enabled on the server and [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) on the client. Typically it's just a matter of installing your distribution's `sshfs` package.

```
sudo pacman -S sshfs
mkdir -p ~/net/vm
sshfs 10.211.55.8: ~/net/vm
ls ~/net/vm/somedir
cp somefile ~/net/vm/somedir
```

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>FTP used to be commonly used without authentication, but this has now largely been supplanted by HTTP(S).</sub> 
<sup>2</sup>  <sub>There's a standard for using TLS with FTP, called [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS), but it never really took on.</sub>